# SQL Server: Select hierarchically related items from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

Say, I have an organizational structure that is 5 levels deep:

```
CEO -> DeptHead -> Supervisor -> Foreman -> Worker
```

The hierarchy is stored in a table `Position` like this:

```
PositionId | PositionCode | ManagerId
         1 |          CEO |      NULL
         2 |       DEPT01 |         1
         3 |       DEPT02 |         1
         4 |       SPRV01 |         2
         5 |       SPRV02 |         2
         6 |       SPRV03 |         3
         7 |       SPRV04 |         3
       ... |          ... |       ...
```

`PositionId` is `uniqueidentifier`. `ManagerId` is the ID of employee's manager, referring `PositionId` from the same table.

I need a SQL query to get the hierarchy tree going down from a position, provided as parameter, *including the position itself.* I managed to develop this:

```
-- Select the original position itself
SELECT
'Rank' = 0,
Position.PositionCode
FROM Position
WHERE Position.PositionCode = 'CEO' -- Parameter
-- Select the subordinates
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
'Rank' =
    CASE WHEN Pos2.PositionCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1+
        CASE WHEN Pos3.PositionCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1+
            CASE WHEN Pos4.PositionCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1+
                CASE WHEN Pos5.PositionCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1
                END
            END
        END
    END,
'PositionCode' = RTRIM(ISNULL(Pos5.PositionCode, ISNULL(Pos4.PositionCode, ISNULL(Pos3.PositionCode, Pos2.PositionCode)))),
FROM Position Pos1
LEFT JOIN Position Pos2
ON Pos1.PositionId = Pos2.ManagerId
LEFT JOIN Position Pos3
ON Pos2.PositionId = Pos3.ManagerId
LEFT JOIN Position Pos4
ON Pos3.PositionId = Pos4.ManagerId
LEFT JOIN Position Pos5
ON Pos4.PositionId = Pos5.ManagerId
WHERE Pos1.PositionCode = 'CEO' -- Parameter
ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

It works not only for 'CEO' but for any position, displaying its subordinates. Which gives me the following output:

```
Rank | PositionCode
   0 |          CEO
 ... |          ...
   2 |       SPRV55
   2 |       SPRV68
 ... |          ...
   3 |       FRMN10
   3 |       FRMN12
 ... |          ...
   4 |       WRKR01
   4 |       WRKR02
   4 |       WRKR03
   4 |       WRKR04
```

**My problems are:**

The output does not include intermediate nodes - it will only output end nodes, i.e. workers and intermediate managers which have *no subordinates*. I need all intermediate managers as well.

I have to manually `UNION` the row with original position on top of the output. I there any more elegant way to do this?

I want the output to be sorted in hieararchical tree order. Not all DeptHeads, then all Supervisors, then all Foremen then all workers, but like this:

```
Rank | PositionCode
   0 |          CEO
   1 |       DEPT01
   2 |       SPRV01
   3 |       FRMN01
   4 |       WRKR01
   4 |       WRKR02
 ... |          ...
   3 |       FRMN02
   4 |       WRKR03
   4 |       WRKR04
 ... |          ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try recursice CTE. This task is the basic example for that.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a recursive CTE, the example on TechNet is almost identical to your problem I believe:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Thx, everyone suggesting CTE. I got the following code and it's working okay:

```
WITH HierarchyTree (PositionId, PositionCode, Rank)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT PositionId, PositionCode, 
        0 AS Rank
    FROM Position AS e
    WHERE PositionCode = 'CEO'
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.PositionId, e.PositionCode, 
        Rank + 1
    FROM Position AS e
    INNER JOIN HierarchyTree AS d
        ON e.ManagerId = d.PositionId
)
SELECT Rank, PositionCode
FROM HierarchyTree
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to yours on a recent project but with a variable recursion length - typically between 1 and 10 levels.

I wanted to simplify the SQL side of things so I put some extra work into the logic of storing the recursive elements by storing a "hierarchical path" in addition to the direct manager Id.

So a very contrived example:

Employee

```
Id |  JobDescription   | Hierarchy | ManagerId
1  |  DIRECTOR         |   1\      |   NULL
2  |  MANAGER 1        |   1\2\    |   1
3  |  MANAGER 2        |   1\3\    |   1
4  |  SUPERVISOR 1     |   1\2\4   |   2
5  |  SUPERVISOR 2     |   1\3\5   |   3
6  |  EMPLOYEE 1       |   1\2\4\6 |   4
7  |  EMPLOYEE 2       |   1\3\5\7 |   5
```

This means you have the power to very quickly query any level of the tree and get all descendants by using a LIKE query on the Hierarchy column

For example

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee WHERE Hierarchy LIKE '\1\2\%'
```

would return

```
MANAGER 1
SUPERVISOR 1
EMPLOYEE 1
```

Additionally you can also easily get one level of the tree by using the `ManagerId` column.

The downside to this approach is you have to construct the hierarchy when inserting or updating records but believe me when I say this storage structure saved me a lot of pain later on without the need for unnecessary query complexity.

One thing to note is that my approach gives you the raw data - I then parse the result set into a recursive strongly typed structure in my services layer. As a rule I don't tend to format output in SQL.